# SQL IN equivalent in CAML

Tags: sql, sharepoint-2007, caml, where-in

Is there a "nice" way to create a CAML query for SharePoint that does something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Id IN (3, 12, ...)
```

Or am I stuck with a nightmare of nested `<Or>` nodes?

---

EDIT: This was my solution to generate the `<Or>` nodes.

```
/// Simulates a SQL 'Where In' clause in CAML
/// </summary>
/// <param name="columnType">Specifies the data type for the value contained by the field.</param>
/// <returns>Nested 'Or' elements portion of CAML query</returns>
public static string CamlIn<T>(string internalFieldName, string columnType, T[] values)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();
    XElement prev = null;
    int index = 0;

    while (index < values.Length)
    {
        XElement element =
            new XElement("Or",
                new XElement("Eq",
                    new XElement("FieldRef",
                    new XAttribute("Name", internalFieldName)),
                new XElement("Value",
                    new XAttribute("Type", columnType),
                    values[index++].ToString())));

        if (index == values.Length - 1)
        {
            element.AddFirst(
                new XElement("Eq",
                    new XElement("FieldRef",
                    new XAttribute("Name", internalFieldName)),
                new XElement("Value",
                    new XAttribute("Type", columnType),
                    values[index++].ToString())));
        }

        if (prev != null)
            prev.AddFirst(element);
        else
            doc.Add(element);

        prev = element;
    }

    return doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
string query = string.Format("<Where>{0}</Where>", CamlIn("SomeColumn", "Number", ids));
```

Output:

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Or>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name=\"SomeColumn\" />
                    <Value Type=\"Number\">5</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name=\"SomeColumn\" />
                    <Value Type=\"Number\">4</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name=\"SomeColumn\" />
                <Value Type=\"Number\">2</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name=\"SomeColumn\" />
            <Value Type=\"Number\">1</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

Also made this overload for working with Lookup Fields a bit easier

```
/// <summary>
/// Simulates a SQL 'Where In' clause in CAML
/// </summary>
/// <param name="lookupId">Specify whether to use the Lookup column's Id or Value.</param>
/// <returns>Nested 'Or' elements portion of CAML query</returns>
public static string CamlIn<T>(string internalFieldName, bool lookupId, T[] values)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();
    XElement prev = null;
    int index = 0;

    while (index < values.Length)
    {
        XElement element =
            new XElement("Or",
                new XElement("Eq",
                    new XElement("FieldRef",
                        new XAttribute("Name", internalFieldName),
                        lookupId ? new XAttribute("LookupId", "TRUE") : null),
                    new XElement("Value",
                        new XAttribute("Type", "Lookup"),
                        values[index++].ToString())));

        if (index == values.Length - 1)
        {
            element.AddFirst(
                new XElement("Eq",
                    new XElement("FieldRef",
                        new XAttribute("Name", internalFieldName),
                        lookupId ? new XAttribute("LookupId", "TRUE") : null),
                    new XElement("Value",
                        new XAttribute("Type", "Lookup"),
                        values[index++].ToString())));
        }

        if (prev != null)
            prev.AddFirst(element);
        else
            doc.Add(element);

        prev = element;
    }

    if (values.Length == 1)
    {
        XElement newRoot = doc.Descendants("Eq").Single();
        doc.RemoveNodes();
        doc.Add(newRoot);
    }

    return doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO, you'll need to deal with nested `OR` tags; these are [supported query instructions on CAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx)

Maybe [CAML.NET](http://codeplex.com/camldotnet) can help you in your quest.

Answer (score 23):

For those using Sharepoint 2010, there is an IN element available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761.aspx

Here's a working example:

```
SPQuery locationsQuery = new SPQuery();
locationsQuery.Query = string.Concat("<Where>",
                                       "<In>",
                                         "<FieldRef Name='ID' />",
                                           "<Values>",
                                             "<Value Type='Number'>6</Value>",
                                             "<Value Type='Number'>7</Value>",
                                             "<Value Type='Number'>8</Value>",
                                           "</Values>",
                                       "</In>",
                                     "</Where>");
```

Answer (score 5):

**FullTextSqlQuery**

It is possible to search MOSS using SQL statements, using the [FullTextSqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.fulltextsqlquery.aspx) class.  I have no experience of using this class personally.  These articles may be of use:

- http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/ricardocosta/archive/2007/06/15/How-to-use-FullTextSqlQuery-to-search-in-WSS.aspx
- http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/03/06/how-to-use-the-moss-enterprise-search-fulltextsqlquery-class.aspx

**YACAMLQT**

Alternatively, there is also [YACAMLQT (Yet Another CAML Query Tool)](http://yacamlqt.codeplex.com/) which allows you to create SharePoint CAML queries using a T-SQL syntax.

**LINQ to SharePoint**

If you are up to speed with LINQ, then the [LINQ to SharePoint project](http://linqtosharepoint.codeplex.com/) provides a tool to query SharePoint lists using the LINQ syntax.  Please note, this tool is still in the alpha testing phase, so it may not be production ready.

**U2U CAML Query Builder**

If you are working with CAML queries, I would recommend using the [U2U CAML Query Builder for SharePoint](http://www.u2u.be/Res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) (2003 and 2007) tool to build up your CAML queries.  The tool allows you to build up your query string, and to execute it against the target list, using a point-and-click interface, as shown below.

[image: U2U CAML Query Builder for SharePoint in action]
<sub>(source: [u2u.net](http://www.u2u.net/res/Images/Tools/CQB/buildwhereclause6.png))</sub>

Of the above four methods, I can recommend the U2U CAML Query Builder, having used it almost daily over the last 6 months.  It also appears to be the most widely used CAML tool in the SharePoint community .

Note, if you are building the CAML queries in code, then I recommend that you take a look at the [CAML.NET project](http://www.codeplex.com/camldotnet) on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com), which provides "*a set of .NET language-based tools for creating dynamic, reusable CAML query components*".

Comment: Didn't know about CAML.NET. May need to use that in the future.  I did something similar with XElements to generate the necessary `<Or>`s.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar thing and ultimately had to create a recursive algorithm to generate the nested OR structure. Here is my algorithm

```
var DynamicQuery = '<Query><Where>{{DYNAMICSTRING}}</Where></Query>';
var OneOR = '<Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="IMEI" /><Value Type="Text">{{SearchValue}}</Value></Eq>{{DYNAMICSTRING}}</Or>';
var TwoOr = '<Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="IMEI" /><Value Type="Text">{{SearchValue}}</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="IMEI" /><Value Type="Text">{{SearchValue}}</Value></Eq></Or>';
var OnlyEq =  '<Eq><FieldRef Name="IMEI" /><Value Type="Text">{{SearchValue}}</Value></Eq>';
function generateAdvancedInQuery(x){
    if(x.length == 1)
        return OnlyEq.replace('{{SearchValue}}',x[0]);
    else if(x.length == 2)
        return TwoOr.replace('{{SearchValue}}',x[0]).replace('{{SearchValue}}',x[1]);
    else 
        return OneOR.replace('{{SearchValue}}',x[x.length-1]).replace('{{DYNAMICSTRING}}',generateAdvancedInQuery(x.splice(0,x.length-1) ) );   
}

x = ['438753234098792','438753234098793','438753234098794','438753234098795','438753234098796','438753234098797','438753234098798'];

var Caml = DynamicQuery.replace('{{DYNAMICSTRING}}',generateAdvancedInQuery(x) )
```

This generates the XML caml query as

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="IMEI" />
                <Value Type="Text">438753234098798</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="IMEI" />
                    <Value Type="Text">438753234098797</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="IMEI" />
                        <Value Type="Text">438753234098796</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Or>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name="IMEI" />
                            <Value Type="Text">438753234098795</Value>
                        </Eq>
                        <Or>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name="IMEI" />
                                <Value Type="Text">438753234098794</Value>
                            </Eq>
                            <Or>
                                <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name="IMEI" />
                                    <Value Type="Text">438753234098792</Value>
                                </Eq>
                                <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name="IMEI" />
                                    <Value Type="Text">438753234098793</Value>
                                </Eq>
                            </Or>
                        </Or>
                    </Or>
                </Or>
            </Or>
        </Or>
    </Where>
</Query>
```