# Query large Document Library to get 100 Items only

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

(SharePoint 2010, Visual Studio, C#)

I have a large SharePoint Document Library called LargeLib (and am concerned about performance).

I have about 100 IDs and I have to extract respective items (with just 3 columns ID, Name, Author).

The CAML Query seems to be very large, as there is no "IS IN" clause possible in CAML. I have to repeat CAML lines of code a hundred times. WIll this be a good option? I wish I could pass it an array of IDs.

Do we have any other performance friendly option?

Thanks a lot in advance as I am stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891303/sql-in-equivalent-in-caml) seems to be the same as what you're asking.  He solved it by building a function for nesting OR nodes...

One of the answers discusses using the `<IN>` node for SharePoint 2010, so I guess you're in luck:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761.aspx

HTH