# What is the limit of nested OR's in a CAML Query?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

From the question '[**SQL IN equivalent in CAML**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891303/sql-in-equivalent-in-caml)' I learned that SharePoint 2010 has a SQL "IN" equivalent for CAML. Also that the 2007 version does not support this. The OP solved this by nesting a bunch of OR statements to achieve the same result. I tested this and the nesting indeed does the magic, but...

In my case I'm getting items from a list with around a 1000 items. I dynamically create a statement with all the IDs in nested OR-blocks for my CAML-query. I didn't worry about the big number of nested blocks as [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472196%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is what MSDN states about the OR-element:

`Occurrences: Minimum: 0, Maximum: Unbounded.`

and:

`This element can be nested inside other Or and And elements. The server supports unlimited complicated queries.`

When I call the *GetListItems*-method from the SharePoint 2007 built-in webservice, I get following error:

`Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown. Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.`

My code is written correctly because I tested the same code with only 5 nested Or-elements and the result is as expected. My question is: what IS the limit of nested Or-elements? I cannot find this anywhere as Microsoft claims this is unlimited.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to run the query in [CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx). You can choose to query using Object Model or Web Services - see if you get the same problem there or there is another problem with your query.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but in the meanwhile I already found the solution. Thanks anyway! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those facing the same problem. I went for a search on SharePoint.StackExchange.com and found the following question:

- [Nested CAML Query results in exception “ Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries”](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6531/nested-caml-querie-results-in-exception-some-part-of-your-sql-statement-is-nes)

One of the answers points to this website:

- [CAML: Nested Too Deep](http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.be/2007/05/caml-nested-too-deep.html)

The person discovered that 500 items was too much but that a batch of 300 worked fine. So I tried this and this also works for me. So for anyone that faces the same problem, this might be the solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

Same problem with `SP2010` and nested `OR`s, breaks when reaching 160+ nested items.

Error raised is not very helpful (`System.ArgumentException`) when trying to get the `SPListItemCollection = List.GetItems(Query);`
Looks like SQL server refuse to execute the query.

Solution is to break in multiple queries or change the way of querying.

Comment: I meet the same issue. Can you tell more about your solution. Btw, Many thanks.